# Поиск в каталоге /dev на Linux

Tags: linux

Нужно осуществить поиск в каталоге /dev и найти 5 15 и 25 оборудование...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Имеете ввиду что-то вроде этого?

```
find /dev \( -name 5 -or -name 15 -or -name 25 \) \( -type b -or -type c \)
```

Comment: Оу! Как я Вам благодарен=)

Comment: если у кого-то еще какие-то предложения есть принимаются!

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
for myfile in /dev/*
do
if [ -b "$myfile" ]
then
myvar=$(( $myvar + 1 ))
if [ "$myvar" = 5 ]
then
echo "$myfile" "$myvar"
fi
if [ "$myvar" = 15 ]
then
echo "$myfile" "$myvar"
fi
if [ "$myvar" = 25 ]
then
echo "$myfile" "$myvar"
fi
fi
done
```

Comment: так правильнее=)